# ARM MBED CoAP example mot opening port

Tags: arm, mbed, coap

I have succesfully built the CoAP protocol example for ARM mbed (https://developer.mbed.org/teams/sandbox/code/coap-example/file/0681e205d0e9/) on a K64F board. It comes out of the box, except for the server name (coap.me) changed to an internal IP address.

I see that it runs correctly and connects to the network:

```
[EasyConnect] Using Ethernet
[EasyConnect] Connected to Network successfully
[EasyConnect] IP address 192.168.1.15
[EasyConnect] MAC address 0e:43:54:d9:7c:71
Connected to the network. Opening a socket...
Calculated message length: 11 bytes
Starting server
Sent 11 bytes to coap://192.168.1.10:5683
```

I have set a computer that can connect to it. It can ping correctly to the board and I see that the ARP is negotiating with the correct MAC address.

I have launched an NMAP test and I see that the port is closed:

```
PORT     STATE     SERVICE
5683/udp closed    unknown
```

If I set a CoAP client in the computer (Copper) I see no connection in the terminal.

What I am missing?

Comment: Where does the message gets lost? The computer does not receive the request, or the board does not receive the response?

coap-example is only tested with device -> server -> device, not server -> device -> server...

Comment: Board -> Computer message arrives (I have no server on it but tcpdump sees it)

Comment: Computer -> Board message is not received. (I see no trace on the terminal)

Comment: Board -> Board (Two different boards running the same example) - I see no trace of the communication on any side

Comment: As I understand it, the example is just sending a message to a server and receiving the answer. To create a server I need to open the port using socket.bind(5683). Is that what I am missing?

Comment: Yeah, I think for UDP calling `bind()` and then having a `recvfrom` hook is enough...

Comment: It works. I am on the next problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to the answer section as well, in case someone else runs into this problem.

If you want to use an mbed OS 5 device as a UDP *server*, make sure to call `.bind()` on the socket.

Comment: socket.bind(5683);